# JSF Application list files from src/main/resources/somefolder

Tags: java, jsf, maven, resources

I'm trying to get a list of files from a folder in the src/main/resources directory of my webapp. Does anyone have a solution ?
So, one problem is, that I have only the glassfish.jar in my classpath.
I don't find an entrypoint from where I can start.
It's a maven project.

Regards,
Holger

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're after here. Do you want to do this programatically or just as a one-off. If the latter then you can open your war file with pkzip (for example) and navigate into it.

Comment: I'm trying to get an array of filenames programmatically. Like String[] files = getFilesFromResourcePath("targetDirectory");
And these files are located in /src/main/resources/targetDirectory

Comment: Why you want that? Unless you are writing unit tests, this does not make too much sense. Files under resources will go to the root directory in your war file. So if you do getFilesList("/src/main/resources/targetDirectory") will not work once your app is deployed.

Comment: I have some xml files that have to be processed. So, where should I place them in a standard maven project. I thought this should be in the resources directory. BTW, these files will be in the web-inf/classes directory after deloyment.

Comment: Concerning the test resources, you also have resources for the tests under src/test/resources

Comment: To make it clearer: I need to get a list of files, which reside after the deployment in web-inf/classes/someDirectory/*

Answer (score 0):

The solution so far :
which works, but doesn't satisfy me, because of the absolute path.

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils has to be included.

```
public Collection<File> queryResourceFileCollectionByDirectoryMember(Class clazz, String resourcePathToMember, String[] extensions) {
    logger.info("------- FileTools : queryResourceFileCollectionByDirectoryMember");

    try {
        //String[] extensions = {"xml"};
        URL resourceURL = clazz.getResource(resourcePathToMember);//"/fields/testOITM.xml" <- one XML file in the /src/main/resources/fields/ folder to get the absolutepath which after deployment is WEB-INF/classes/fields
        String resourcePath = resourceURL.getPath();

        //Remove the leading slash
        String resourcePathWithoutFirstChar = resourcePath.substring(1);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "------- FileTools : queryResourceFileCollectionByDirectoryMember: resourcePath :{0} :", resourcePathWithoutFirstChar);
        File resourceFileToGetDirectory = new File(resourcePathWithoutFirstChar);
        String resourceDirectoryPath = resourceFileToGetDirectory.getParent() + File.separator; //"c:/Users/xuser/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BOneBApp/target/classes/"
        File resourceDirectory = new File(resourceDirectoryPath);
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(resourceDirectory, extensions, true);
        return files;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "******* FileTools : queryResourceFileCollectionByDirectoryMember : {0}", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

The clazz can be any class of the webapp.

Regards,
Holger

Comment: This doesn't work if the class is inside an unexpanded WAR/JAR.

Comment: That's right, but the applications requirements are in this case, that the war is exploded. What would be the right code for an unexploded war ??

Comment: How do you call the function in xhtml? What is clazz for?